Error al crear página en GitHub
Creé una página web mediante "github pages". No es la primera vez que lo hago, de hecho, ya tengo varias páginas hechas y sin ningún problema. El contenido es sólo HTML, CSS y JavaScript puro, con algunas imágenes que, en total, pesan 1.66 Mb. La página entera pesa 1.74 MB. Aclaro que NO hay errores de código, y la página está subida a la rama "Master" de GitHub.
Había subido una página llamada "PADAAR-Electro" y no tuve ningún inconveniente. Pero luego de agregar algunos textos más a la página, hacer el "commit" y el "push", me llegó una notificación al correo electrónico que dice lo siguiente:

Luego, cuando entro a "GitHub" me encuentro con lo siguiente:

Quisiera que, por favor, me ayuden a encontrar la solución al problema y, desde ya, muchas gracias .

Borrar todo y volver a subir??

Lo había pensado, pero antes quería ver si había alguna lógica en el error y si tenía solución, por si le pasó a alguien más lo mismo.

Pude solucionar el problema.
Para el que le sirva, lo único que hice fue hacer un modificación en el HTML (cambié una foto), lo agregué con git add . ,  hice un commit -m , un push y cuando voy a mi GitHub-pages ya la página se había actualizado correctamente.
Saludos!
